# AppCombat v21 TextAppearance on Gingerbread with DarkActionBar

Tags: android, android-2.3-gingerbread

i recently updated the appcombat library to integrate the material design.
But there is an issue with the style "Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar", because if i use this style and let my TextView like:

```
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall
```

the whole text appears invisible (or just white) on a white background

If a use the "Theme.AppCompat.Light" theme, everything is working fine.
This issue i have only on Devices running android 2.3.*

Samples: (Don't have enough reputation to post images, so you need to click)

[DarkActionBar:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJdh7.png)

[Light:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4aPn.png)

Any suggestions guys? Anyone tried the new appcombat library with Gingerbread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously i found out that i need to use material text appeareance, for instance:

```
android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
```

See also:
http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/typography.html#typography-roboto-noto